# Adding a UPN, when I log in using that UPN it doesn't use the same profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I added a UPN to our AD Domain and to test I logged in using the new UPN as my user. Unfortunately, this for some reason used a new profile and I lost all of the bookmarks, cookies, settings, etc that had been set when using the old login.

For example, the domain was set up as domain.local and that is what we've been using for years. In order to get ready to migrate to Azure and use Azure AD, one of the instructions is to create/use a domain/FQDN that is WAn routable, so obviously .local domains won't work. A suggested solution in the MSFT docs was this creating a UPN, however I'm coming across this issue now where it's not using the same/old profile. I can't have users lose their profiles especially cookies while doign this.

Is this expected behavior or am/did I do something wrong. From my research, it seems like it should not be using a new profile and should be using the same profile as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses the user account SID to keep track and relate user profiles to Active Directory users. Changing the UPN or the SamAccountName does not change the SID of a user account. In fact, the SID is immutable.

If you only changed the UPN, this has no impact on the SID and consequently to the user profile that is loaded when you log on to a computer where you logged in before the change.

If you experience an issue with the user profile, the cause does not correlate to the change.

Comment: OK, so it depends on if the users has logged onto the machine before. If so, it should use the same profile as before the UPN change. Thanks. Nice avi, btw.